# Android open an external directory using an intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

There is not a straightforward or a clear way to make an implicit intent to open a folder/directory in Android.
Specifically here I want to open `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`.

I tried these ones but they will just open a `FileManager` app, not the directory I want:

```
val directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
val uri = Uri.parse(directory.path)
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*")
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(openIntent, "Open Folder"))
```

Another example:

```
val directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
val uri = Uri.parse(directory.path)
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder")
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(openIntent, "Open Folder"))
```

Comment: "There is not a straightforward or a clear way to make an implicit intent to open a folder/directory in Android" -- that is because there has never been official support for this in Android.

Comment: Somebody should create a library to open directories. Or we guys on StackOverflow should go to Github and create a new open-source project, because contrary to what Google is doing right now, there are many apps that need to open directories to work and fulfill their objective.

Comment: @GauravMall couldn't agree more!

Comment: @GauravMall I guess it would be awesome to have an intent helper library to include all implicit intents, from taking pictures, calling and dialing to sharing files and opening them

Answer (score 3):

### Opening 'THE' `Downloads` folder

If you want to open the downloads folder, you need to use `DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS`, like this:

```
Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
downloadIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(downloadIntent);
```

No need to use mime type `resource/folder` as Android doesn't have an official folder mime type, so you could produce some errors in some devices. Your device seems not to support that mime type. You need to use the code above, as it just passes to the intent the official folder you want to go to.

---

**Edit:** For other custom directories, I don't think that you can just pass a path to the intent like the one. I don't think that there is a reliable way to open a folder in Android.

---

### Using `FileProvider`(Test)

**Edit:** Try instead of just parsing the `Uri`, if you are using `FileProvider`, which you should, use `getUriForFile()`. Like this:

```
val dir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
val intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
val mydir = getUriForFile(context, "paste_your_authority", dir)
intent.setDataAndType(mydir, "resource/folder")
startActivity(intent);
```

or instead of using `resource/folder`, use:

```
DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR
```

### Moral of the story:

There is no standard way of opening files. Every device is different and the code above is **not** guaranteed to work in every single device.

Comment: No, this will open the downloads folder, I want to open my apps download directory `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`

Comment: Oh okay, didn't understand you. Going to update this question.

Comment: `FileProvider.getUriForFile` didn't work as well. I also tried it with `DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR`

Comment: By the way, are you testing this on an emulator? If not, what device are you using?

Comment: I'm testing on Pixel2 Android 9 and 10. And there are a couple of file manager apps installed on them

Comment: Weird that my options don't work. Try using `application/*` or `text/csv`